# $P(x, y)$ for which $\exists x\forall yP(x, y)$ and $\exists y\forall xP(x, y)$ are not equivalent

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The domain of $x$ and $y$ is the same, real numbers. I was wondering if there was a $P(x)$ for which these two would be non equivalent.

Comment: ... or rather $P(x,y)\equiv x\le y^2$. Or simply $P(x,y)\equiv x=42$.

Comment: Natural numbers, $P=\le$.

Answer (score 3):

You could let $P(x,y)$ mean $x=0$. (Yes, $y$ deliberately doesn't appear there).

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider:

$$P(x,y)="y\times\lfloor x^2+1\rfloor\text{ is an integer}".$$

Then

$$\exists x,\quad\forall y,\quad P(x,y)$$

is false since the domain you consider is the set of real numbers.

But

$$\exists y,\quad\forall x,\quad P(x,y)$$

is true (you can take $y=0$ or $y=k\in \mathbb Z$ for instance).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oops, the "$y$" disappeared mysteriously. I edited.